# Laravel json column show in view

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a json column called additional_info. I want to be able to return the data held there with foreach as follows.

```
<a href="additional_info->Addslack->slack"><i class="additional_info->Addslack->icon"></i> additional_info->Addslack->title </a>
    
    
<a href="additional_info->Addgithub->github"><i class="additional_info->Addgithub->icon"></i> additional_info->Addgithub>title </a>
```

... like this

```
{
  ....., 
  "Addphone":{
    "icon":"fas fa-phone-alt",
    "phone":"12345",
    "title":"work"
  },
  "Addskype":{
    "icon":"fab fa-skype",
    "skype":null,
    "title":null
  },
  "Addslack":{
    "icon":"fab fa-slack-hash",
    "slack":"slack_address",
    "title":null
  },
  "Addgithub":{
    "icon":"fab fa-github",
    "title":"git",
    "github":"cnahmetcn",
  },
  ....
}
```

how can I do that? There are dozens of data like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($card->additional_info as $key=>$value)
                            @if(is_object($value) || is_array($value))
                                @foreach($value as $key2=>$value2)
                                    @if ($value2 != null)
                                    {{$key2}} :  {{$value2}} <br>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                            @endforeach
```

i have run this code but i am not getting the result i want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a cast on yout model

```
protected $casts = [
  'column' => 'json'  
];
```

This cast will already convert the json to vector at the time of feeding the model

Comment: I already did this. But since it is a nested json I can't get the foreach e like this.